# SL Baremetal order with RAID disks ---> The location provided for this order is invalid

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I try to order a Baremetal machine but I get that error

```
root@ubuntu:~# ruby array.rb
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/1.9.1/xmlrpc/client.rb:414:in `call': The location provided for this order is invalid. (XMLRPC::FaultException)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/softlayer_api-3.0.2/lib/softlayer/Service.rb:267:in `call_softlayer_api_with_params'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/softlayer_api-3.0.2/lib/softlayer/Service.rb:196:in `method_missing'
from array.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

I've also tried to use lon02 (id 358694) but I catch the same error.

I want to automate the order for following configuration:

```
Server:
 Dual Intel Xeon E5-2650 (8 Cores, 2.00 GHz)
 Second Processor Intel Xeon E5-2650 (8 Cores, 2.00 GHz)
RAM:
 16 GB
Operating System:
 Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr - Minimal Install (64 bit)
Disk Controller:
 RAID
10 Hard Drives of type:
 800 GB SSD (10 DWPD)
 Disk 0-3 Raid 6. Disk 4 HotSpare - Disk 5-8 Raid 6 Disk 9 HotSpare
Public Bandwidth:
 500 GB Bandwidth
Uplink Port Speeds:
 1 Gbps Redundant Public & Private Network Uplinks
 Private Network Port 1 Gbps Redundant Private Uplinks
 Public Network Port 1 Gbps Redundant Public Uplinks
Power Supply:
 Redundant Power Supply
Monitoring:
 Host Ping and TCP Service Monitoring
Response:
 Automated Reboot from Monitoring
VPN Management - Private Network:
 Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account
Vulnerability Assessments & Management:
 Nessus Vulnerability Assessment & Reporting
Primary IP Addresses:
 1 IP Address
Notification:
 Email and Ticket
Remote Management:
 Reboot / KVM over IP
```

This is my code snippet:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'

$SL_API_USERNAME = "-------"
$SL_API_KEY = "------------------"

client = SoftLayer::Service.new("SoftLayer_Product_Order");
product={
"complexType"=>"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server", 
"quantity"=>1, 
"hardware"=>[{"hostname"=>"dysa-ca-east-0-baremetal-uaa-test-ai", "domain"=>"dysa-ca-east", "primaryNetworkComponent"=>{"networkVlan"=>{"id"=>"888013"}}, "primaryBackendNetworkComponent"=>{"networkVlan"=>{"id"=>"888015"}}}], 
"location"=>"448994", 
"packageId"=>142, 
"prices"=>[{"id"=>29899}, {"id"=>29899}, {"id"=>37622}, {"id"=>34742}, {"id"=>36037}, {"id"=>35529}, {"id"=>35529}, {"id"=>35529}, {"id"=>35529}, {"id"=>35529}, {"id"=>35529}, {"id"=>35529}, {"id"=>35529}, {"id"=>35529}, {"id"=>35529}, {"id"=>33867}, {"id"=>26109}, {"id"=>25014}, {"id"=>34807}, {"id"=>34241}, {"id"=>32500}, {"id"=>34996}, {"id"=>33483}, {"id"=>35310}], "useHourlyPricing"=>false, 
"storageGroups"=>[{"arrayTypeId"=>"4", "hardDrives"=>"[0,1,2,3]", "hotSpareDrives"=>"[4]"}, {"arrayTypeId"=>"4", "hardDrives"=>"[5,6,7,8]", "hotSpareDrives"=>"[9]"}]}
client.verifyOrder(product)
```

Could you pls help me?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This request may help you to get valid item prices according to location:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/200/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[id,item[keyName,description],pricingLocationGroup[locations[id, name, longName]]]

Method: GET
```

**Where:**
These price ids with a locationGroupId = null are considered as "a standard price" and the API will internally switch the prices for the customer. But it is recommend first to execute first the verifyOrder in order to see if the wanted order is ok (the fee can vary).
To get more details about this, please review:

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/Location-based-Pricing-and-You

This is another example using itemPrices in PHP.

https://softlayer.github.io/php/get_required_price_id/

If the problem persists, please open a SL ticket because it could be a bug.

**References:**

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/Location-based-Pricing-and-You
>   http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices
>   http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects
>   http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package

Comment: all item id ordered have locationGroupId = null

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue, the package you are using does not have any available datacenter you can verify that by running this method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getRegions

here an example using rest:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/142/getRegions

method: GET
```

That's why you are getting the error: The location provided for this order is invalid.

I suggest you open a ticket in Softlayer's Portal and report the issue, meanwhile you can try another package (if you want it).

Regards

Comment: For item 142 I have a simple "<root/>"

Comment: It is empty it should display all available dacenters, if you try with another package such as the 200 you will see the diference

Answer (score 0):

partially resolved used packageId=251 but the ordered bare metal have 10xRAID 0 each with only 1 disk instead of 2xRAID 6 :((((
What is wrong in the following code?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'softlayer_api'

$SL_API_USERNAME = "-----"
$SL_API_KEY = "-----"

client = SoftLayer::Service.new("SoftLayer_Product_Order");
product={
"complexType"=>"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server",
"quantity"=>1,
"hardware"=>[{"hostname"=>"dys1-0-baremetal-uaa",
"domain"=>"softlayer.com",
"primaryNetworkComponent"=>{"networkVlan"=>{"id"=>"MY_VLAN_ID"}},
"primaryBackendNetworkComponent"=>{"networkVlan"=>{"id"=>"MY_VLAN_ID"}}}],
"location"=>"358694",
"packageId"=>251,
"prices"=>[{"id"=>50675},
    {"id"=>37622},
    {"id"=>49427},
    {"id"=>141945},
    {"id"=>50143},
    {"id"=>50143},
    {"id"=>50143},
    {"id"=>50143},
    {"id"=>50143},
    {"id"=>50143},
    {"id"=>50143},
    {"id"=>50143},
    {"id"=>50143},
    {"id"=>50143},
    {"id"=>50263},
    {"id"=>26109},
    {"id"=>25014},
    {"id"=>34807},
    {"id"=>50223},
    {"id"=>34241},
    {"id"=>32500},
    {"id"=>34996},
    {"id"=>33483},
    {"id"=>35310}],
"useHourlyPricing"=>false,
"storageGroups"=>[{"arrayTypeId"=>4,
"hardDrives"=>[0,1,2,3],
"hotSpareDrives"=>[4]},
{"arrayTypeId"=>4,
"hardDrives"=>[5,6,7,8],
"hotSpareDrives"=>[9]}]
}

p client.verifyOrder(product)
```

Comment: any idea about that behavior?